# How to create an animated slide menu that partially pushes one view out to the right

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

How can I create a slide menu like [image: this]
I have come across code that can allow me to partially push the view to the left but how can i do the same such that when one view is pushed out, the next gets pulled in.

Here is what I am currently working with

```
    NavigationIconClickListener(Context context, View sheet) {
    this(context, sheet, null);
}

NavigationIconClickListener(Context context, View sheet, @Nullable Interpolator interpolator) {
    this(context, sheet, interpolator, null, null);
}

NavigationIconClickListener(
        Context context, View sheet, @Nullable Interpolator interpolator,
        @Nullable Drawable openIcon, @Nullable Drawable closeIcon) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sheet = sheet;
    this.interpolator = interpolator;
    this.openIcon = openIcon;
    this.closeIcon = closeIcon;

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    height = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    backdropShown = !backdropShown;

    // Cancel the existing animations
    animatorSet.removeAllListeners();
    animatorSet.end();
    animatorSet.cancel();

    updateIcon(view);

    final int translateY = height -
            context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.grid_reveal_height);

    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sheet, "translationX", backdropShown ? translateY : 0);
    animator.setDuration(500);
    if (interpolator != null) {
        animator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    }
    animatorSet.play(animator);
    animator.start();
}
```

And I call that like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new NavigationIconClickListener(this,findViewById(R.id.dashboard)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using MotionLayout. Create two layouts. One with the menu open and one with the menu closed. Then define a Transition. When the user wants to open the menu just call to start the transition.
For a complete answer you can read the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout